# correlate two data sets of different scales

Tags: r, curve-fitting

How do we correlate two data sets/curves which have different scales, i.e. one curve has its y axis range from (0,70000) and another curve has y axis range from (0, 150000). If they are on same scale, then cor() function can be used. I wanted to check if one curve is dependent on other/ are both curves related. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

If you have a look at the [definition of Pearson's product moment of correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence) (which is what `cor` calculates by default), you will see it is a linear operator. That is, if a and b are constants, then cor(aX + b, Y) = cor(X, Y). So, differences in range between X and Y are not important. Keep in mind though that this correlation only measures **linear dependence**: they may be "related" but have a low correlation. This can happen if the relationship is non-linear, for example:

```
set.seed(100)
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- x^2
cor(x,y)
# 0.1224623
```

Comment: Can this be used to measure similarity between two curves ? Suppose there are two 1-d datasets with very different ranges but similar shape. Can the above correlation be an appropriate measure of similarity between them ?

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for correlation between two sets of data, the amount of correlation is not dependent on differences in the range of the data sets.

For example, we can make a random set of `y` values and then scale them up. The correlation is still 1:

```
> y <- rnorm(100)
> y2 <- y*2 + 20
> cor(y, y2)
[1] 1
```

To further show that the amount of correlation is independent of linear changes in scale, look at the case with uncorrelated data:

```
> y3 = rnorm(100)
> cor(y, y3)
[1] -0.05293818
> y4 <- y3*2 + 20
> cor(y, y4)
[1] -0.05293818
```

So, to answer your question. I think the function `cor` should still work fine for you.

Answer (score 0):

The correlation shouldn't depend on the absolute ranges of the data, I wouldn't think.  Just multiply one data set by a constant so that it has the same range as the other?